# Poor performance filtering mysql spatial join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

First of all, sorry for the crossposting. I [ask this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974837/poor-performance-filtering-mysql-spatial-join?noredirect=1#comment46219665_28974837) and they sent me here

I have a mysql table with spatial references (GEOGRAPHIC_FILTER), like cities, countries, natural parks, etc, each with a GEOMETRY field. I use this table to "filter" other feature tables with spatial entities (hiking tracks, mtb tracks) by spatial clauses from the geographic filter name (f.e. find hiking trails near paris (france)). But Im getting very poor performance when I try to refine this spatial queries with alphanumerical clauses.

First table: 130.000 records

```
CREATE TABLE `GEOGRAPHIC_FILTER` (
    `pk_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` TEXT NULL,
    `friendly_url` TEXT NULL,
    `type` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `bbox` GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
    `country_code` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `country_name_es` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `simple_name` TEXT NULL,
    `weight` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
    SPATIAL INDEX `bbox` (`bbox`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `name` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Second table: 150.000 records.

```
CREATE TABLE `hiking_trails` (
    `PK_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `BBOX` POLYGON NOT NULL,
    `COUNTER` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `FRIENDLY_URL` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `USERNAME_FK` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `PRODUCER` TEXT NULL,
    `SERVICE_URL` TEXT NULL,
    `TITLE` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    `MAP_TYPE` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `DESCRIPTION` TEXT NULL,
    `SERVICE_LOGO` TEXT NULL,
    `FK_MAPTYPE_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `PLAIN_TEXT_BODY` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `AREA` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CATEGORY` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `LANG` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MAIN_CATEGORY_ES` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `CATEGORY_EN` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `MAIN_CATEGORY_EN` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `WIKIPEDIA_CATEGORY` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `LINE_LENGTH` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MIN_H` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MAX_H` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `AVG_H` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `AVG_ASPECT_UP` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `AVG_ASPECT_DOWN` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `HARD_INDEX` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ELEVATION_PROFILE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PK_ID`),
    INDEX `FRIENDLY_URL_INDEX` (`FRIENDLY_URL`(333)),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `PLAIN_TEXT_INDEX` (`TITLE`, `DESCRIPTION`, `PLAIN_TEXT_BODY`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Now, Im trying to get 'hiking_trails' records near a given geographic reference (for example "Paris (Francia)" ):

This query runs in 0.2 secs

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.FRIENDLY_URL, t.AREA, t.SERVICE_URL, (
X( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - X( Centroid( g.BBOX ) )
) * ( X( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - X( Centroid( g.BBOX ) ) ) + ( Y( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - Y( Centroid( g.BBOX ) ) ) * ( Y( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - Y( Centroid( g.BBOX ) ) ) AS Square_Dist, t.TITLE, t.DESCRIPTION, t.PRODUCER, t.MAP_TYPE, t.PK_ID, t.LINE_LENGTH, t.MIN_H, t.MAX_H, (
t.MAX_H - t.MIN_H
) AS DESNIVEL, t.AVG_H, t.AVG_ASPECT_UP, t.AVG_ASPECT_DOWN, t.HARD_INDEX
FROM rutas_senderismo AS t
JOIN GEOGRAPHIC_FILTER AS g ON MBRIntersects( t.BBOX, g.BBOX )
WHERE g.name = 'Paris (Francia)'
```

But if we add another filter (trails length, order by trails length, etc) this query runs in more than 30 seconds:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.FRIENDLY_URL, t.AREA, t.SERVICE_URL, (
X( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - X( Centroid( g.BBOX ) )
) * ( X( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - X( Centroid( g.BBOX ) ) ) + ( Y( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - Y( Centroid( g.BBOX ) ) ) * ( Y( Centroid( t.BBOX ) ) - Y( Centroid( g.BBOX ) ) ) AS Square_Dist, t.TITLE, t.DESCRIPTION, t.PRODUCER, t.MAP_TYPE, t.PK_ID, t.LINE_LENGTH, t.MIN_H, t.MAX_H, (
t.MAX_H - t.MIN_H
) AS DESNIVEL, t.AVG_H, t.AVG_ASPECT_UP, t.AVG_ASPECT_DOWN, t.HARD_INDEX
FROM rutas_senderismo AS t
JOIN GEOGRAPHIC_FILTER AS g ON MBRIntersects( t.BBOX, g.BBOX )
WHERE g.name = 'Paris (Francia)'
AND t.LINE_LENGTH < 25000
```

Can I optimize this query?

Comment: Try `SELECT x.* FROM (first query) AS x WHERE x.LINE_LENGTH < 25000 ;` If the first query runs fast enough, this one will do, too.

Comment: Thank you very mutch!!! You solved my day. It works like a charm. Why my first query was so slow? Maybe the sql optimizer could detect these mistakes...

Comment: Th eoptimizer does not always choose the best plan. It probably thinks that using the `LINE_LENGTH < 25000` first is better (but it isn't in your case). So, forcing it to evaluate the subquery first, you avoid this. In other circumstances, this "subquerying" might lead to worse plan, so it's not something you should go and do everywhere.